# RethinkDB Replica Sets and Shards for HA

Tags: rethinkdb, high-availability

I would like some guidance on configuring replicas and shards for RethinkDB cluser.

Let's say my cluster consists of 4 instances, all in the same region but in different AZs. Should I set the number of replicas to 4? What are the tradeoffs between choosing between 3 and 4 replica sets in this configuration? How do I determine how many shards to create and does this impact disk use of performance depending on the number of replica sets I have chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best performance you usually want one shard per server.  (The only exception to this is if your servers have a lot of processors, in which case you might get better performance from having 2-3 shards per server.)  The number of replicas should be at least 3 if you want auto-failover to work; making it higher will allow your cluster to survive a higher number of concurrent server failures.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "a lot of processors?" What are the specs of a server that you would consider putting multiple shards on? Also, can you comment on how/if this would change if one table contains a very large number of rows and is write heavy?

Comment: Each range shard will only use 8 cores at most.  If you have exactly one table and your server has a lot of cores, some of them will sit idle.  In that case having one shard for every 8 cores in your cluster instead of one per server might improve performance.